# converting u_int32_t to char **

Tags: c, function, pointers, type-conversion

I am working with functions (c language )and there is a variable declared as
`u_int32_t value;`

and I have to pass it to a function which takes argument of type `(char **)`

I have tried using value[0] etc but it doesnot work.

How to go ahead with typecasting? or

Is there any workaround for it?

Comment: Yes, change the function parameters.

Comment: Show your code, and your understanding of the function you are calling. Generally speaking, converting a number to some pointer to pointer has no sense. But there are exceptions! Consider also `intptr_t`

Comment: It would help to know what you are trying to do---what is the documentation of this function's `char **` argument?

Comment: did you mean `uint32_t`, not `u_int32_t`? What makes you think you would **have to** pass `value` to that function? What do you think `value[0]` would accomplish anyway?

Comment: char **arguments;
arguments[0] = tf->tf_a1[0];

Comment: char **arguments;
/*tf is a predefined structure which has tf_a1 is declared as i_int32_t I cannot change that*/
arguments[0] = tf->tf_a1[0];
function (arguments);

Answer (score 1):

A `(char **)` type almost certainly means a pointer (*) to either one or else an array of C-string (which is a pointer to its first char, or a `char *`).

The most likely solution is hence to generate a C-string from your integer value, and pass a reference to it to the function you want to call with a `char **` argument. Whether this solves your problem depends on the details of this function and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Not very efficient, but it kinda makes it able to pass arbitrary( generic ) data.